# Vpn on non domain joined laptop

Tags: vpn

Let's assume I have my private laptop running VPN software. The VPN server is authenticating users with AD. If I'm an valid AD user of this domain but my laptop is not domain joined,will I be able to authenticate and access corp resources?

Comment: Impossible to answer I'm afraid. It depends on how AD is set up. AD is able to restrict to domain joined computers only and it depends on how it has been configured.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try and let us know ?

From what I understand, it seems like you can ; everything depends on the vpn and AD settings :

- if VPN only allow "registered" machines and your PC is not : you can't
- if VPN does not restrict "inbound" machines, then I guess you can.
- now the most important thing is the AD settings :

  - if access to a given ressource is limited to specific computer accounts, then, though you could be able to authenticate via VPN, you won't be granted access to that resource ;
  - if access to a given ressource is granted primarily based on user accounts, then you won't have issues using your home laptop.
  - add to that numerous other combinations....

Ask you system admin for more information about the company policy and your VPN software settings.

On a more technical level, msdn says :

> When a computer accesses the network, this means that system services running on the computer in the LocalSystem context are accessing the network resources.

Here none of you services running under LocalSystem context has access to your office network...only the VPN software. So unless specific VPN and/or AD settings are in place, you won't be able to access the company network.